# Shuffle bags on mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, shuffle

I have an example of shuffle bags with node.js is like this:

```
var shuffle = {
    bag:function () {
        var data = [], cursor = -1;
        return {
            add: function (item, num) {
                var i = num || 1;
                while (i--) {
                    data.push(item);
                }
                cursor = data.length - 1;
            },
            next: function () {
                var grab, temp;
                if (cursor < 1) {
                    cursor = data.length - 1;
                    return data[0];
                }
                grab = Math.floor(Math.random() * (cursor + 1));
                temp = data[grab];
                data[grab] = data[cursor];
                data[cursor] = temp;
                cursor--;
                return temp;
            }
        };
    }
};
```

But, I want to make a shuffle bag with mongodb. Does someone know if mongodb has a native thing for converting an entire collection in a sufflebag of docs?

Comment: There's not a "random" document API in MongoDB, if that's what you mean. (Otherwise, I'm really not sure what you're asking -- so some clarification would help).

Comment: Thanks WiredPrairie, I solved this making my own class.. :) thanks.